# How can I use dependency injection in Angular 1 with controllers and services in different namespaces?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection

I am trying to introduce a clean folders structure for the scripts in my project using Angular 1 and TypeScript 2. I want to have one file app.ts where I will declare my app and controllers, services etc. Then in separate folders like Controllers I would like to keep my controllers in separate files.

What I have now does not work properly when I am trying to use namespaces and separate classes. It works fine if I put controllers declaration in a separate file completely using constructor inside instead of the namespaces as in the example below. When I run the application I can see two javascript errors:

*-Uncaught ReferenceError: TypeScript is not defined, at app.ts:6 (in this case TypeScript is my namespace)*

*-Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'BrowseMovieTicketsController' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.10/ng/areq?p0=BrowseMovieTicketsController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined*

In  section of my html file the scripts are included in this ordering:

```
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>  
<script src="/Scripts/TypeScript/app.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/TypeScript/Services/MovieInformationService.js"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/TypeScript/Controllers/BrowseMovieTicketsController.js"></script>
```

**Body of index.html**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BrowseMovieTicketsController">
<a ng-click="GetMovie()">Test</div></div>
```

**File app.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="./../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//Controllers
myApp.controller("BrowseMovieTicketsController", TypeScript.Controllers.BrowseMovieTicketsController);

//Services
myApp.service("MovieInformationService", TypeScript.Services.MovieInformationService);
```

**File BrowseMovieTicketsController.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="./../../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>

namespace  TypeScript.Controllers {

    export class BrowseMovieTicketsController {

        scope: any;
        movieInformationService: Services.MovieInformationService;

        static $inject = ["$scope", "MovieInformationService"];

        constructor($scope: any, MovieInformationService: Services.MovieInformationService) {
            this.scope = $scope;
            this.movieInformationService = MovieInformationService;
        }
    }
}
```

**File MovieInformationService.ts:**

```
namespace TypeScript.Services {
    "use strict";
    export class MovieInformationService {
        public GetMovie() {
            console.log("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to import the namespaces, and use modules over namespaces. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your controller in your module.
Try this:

```
namespace  TypeScript.Controllers {

    export class BrowseMovieTicketsController {

        static $inject = ["$scope", "MovieInformationService"];

        constructor(private $scope: any, private MovieInformationService: Services.MovieInformationService) {
        }
    }
myApp.controller("BrowseMovieTicketsController", TypeScript.Controllers.BrowseMovieTicketsController);
}
```

Same for declare your service